# Dropdown not updating after option click

Tags: flutter, dart

I've made a simple class to store my dropdown options:

```
class ExperienceYearsRepository {
  List<String> returnExperienceYears() {
    return [
      "Menos de 1 ano",
      "Entre 1 e 3 anos",
      "Entre 3 e 5 anos",
      "Mais de 5 anos"
    ];
  }
}
```

Below, there's a dropdown implementation which uses that list, but when any option is clicked, the value displayed inside the dropdown is always the value set as experienceYears.first:

```
String experienceTime = "";
var experienceYearsRepository = ExperienceYearsRepository();
var experienceYears = [];

void initState() {
   experienceYears = experienceYearsRepository.returnExperienceYears();
   super.initState();
}

DropdownButton(
   isExpanded: true,
   value: experienceYears.first,
   items: experienceYears
       .map((experienceYear) => DropdownMenuItem(
             value: experienceYear,
             child: Text(experienceYear.toString()),
           ))
       .toList(),
   onChanged: (selectedExperienceTime) {
     setState(() {
        debugPrint(selectedExperienceTime as String?);
        experienceTime = selectedExperienceTime.toString();
     });
   }),
```

Just to clarify, the debugPrint actually prints the correct dropdown item, so the problem in really about displaying it. Any ideas on how to solve this? I'm pretty new to Flutter and I'm having quite a headache, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
String experienceTime = "";
var experienceYearsRepository = ExperienceYearsRepository();
var experienceYears = [];

void initState() {
experienceYears = experienceYearsRepository.returnExperienceYears();
  experienceTime = experienceYears.first; //assign here
super.initState();
}

DropdownButton(
 isExpanded: true,
 value: experienceTime, //use here
 items: experienceYears
   .map((experienceYear) => DropdownMenuItem(
         value: experienceYear,
         child: Text(experienceYear.toString()),
       ))
   .toList(),
  onChanged: (selectedExperienceTime) {
 setState(() {
    debugPrint(selectedExperienceTime as String?);
    experienceTime = selectedExperienceTime.toString();
 });
 }),
```

Answer (score 1):

The value property of DropdownButton() isn't just for initialization, it the value currently displayed on the menu. Change your onChanged parameter to update it. You can assign it in the init() method.

```
@override
void initState() {
    experienceYears = experienceYearsRepository.returnExperienceYears();
    experienceTime = experienceYears.first; //move initialization here
    super.initState();
}


   DropdownButton(
      isExpanded: true,
      value: experienceTime,   //controlling variable
      items: experienceYears
          .map((experienceYear) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: experienceYear,
                child: Text(experienceYear.toString()),
              ))
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (selectedExperienceTime) {
        setState(
          () {
            debugPrint(selectedExperienceTime as String?);
            experienceTime = selectedExperienceTime.toString(); //update it here
          },
        );
      },
    ),
```